# input text control doesn't work on android google chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to add control on primefaces' inputText.

I have this code :

```
<p:inputText onkeydown="charLimit(event);" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function charLimit(event) {
        alert("test");
        event.target.value = event.target.value.substr(0, 5);
    }
</script>
```

It's working. But if I delete "alert('test')", it doesn't work. Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Edit : I still try to control the input with regexp. But when my regexp doesn't match, the input value is duplicate.

```
<p:inputText id="testtest"  value=""  maxlength="5"  onkeyup="validerRegexp(event, this, '^[A-Z]{0,5}$');" />

function validerRegexp(event, that, regexp){
    var expression = RegExp(regexp);
    var valeur = verifierRegexp(expression, event.target.value);
    if(valeur != null) {
        that.value = event.target.value;
    } else {
        that.value = event.target.value.substring(0,event.target.value.length - 1);
    }
}

function verifierRegexp(expression, valeur){
    var resultat = null;
    if(valeur != null && expression != null){
        var tmp = valeur.match(expression);
        if(tmp !=null && tmp.length > 0){
            resultat = tmp[0];
        }
    }
    return resultat;
}
```

Do you have an idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `maxlength` attribute for your input field.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already try maxlength, it's working with chrome on desktop computer but not with chrome on android.

Comment: acording to [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=maxlength) it is supported after focus is lost. I would try the onkeyup method if you want to delete it immediately.  `
    <input type="text" onkeyup="changeThis(event,this)">
    <script>
        function changeThis(ev, that) {
            that.value = ev.target.value.substring(0, 5);
        }
    </script>` works for me

Comment: I don't understand why but it's working. Thanks you :)

Comment: can't change the value of the event, you have to change the actual value of the element. You're welcome